# Geonode layers not visible on map creation

Tags: geonode

On a geonode 2.4 installations I have hundreds of layers. When creating a new map (as logged in admin) I can see none of them in the available layer tree.  It just stays empty. geonode.log does not show any error.

I recognized that the Geoserver which is running on same machine is not in the list.

Thus, I tried to add it like http://mygeonode.org/wms/ unfortunately this does not work.

This is how my server definition on local settings looks like:

```
    GEOSERVER_URL = SITEURL + 'geoserver/'

# OGC (WMS/WFS/WCS) Server Settings
OGC_SERVER = {
    'default' : {
        'BACKEND' : 'geonode.geoserver',
        'LOCATION' : 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/',
        'PUBLIC_LOCATION' : GEOSERVER_URL,
        'USER' : 'admin',
        'PASSWORD' : 'geoserver',#'password',
        'MAPFISH_PRINT_ENABLED' : True,
        'PRINT_NG_ENABLED' : True,
        'GEONODE_SECURITY_ENABLED' :True,
        'GEOGIG_ENABLED' : False,
        'WMST_ENABLED' : False,
        'BACKEND_WRITE_ENABLED': True,
        'WPS_ENABLED' : True,
        'LOG_FILE':'/usr/share/geoserver/data/logs/geoserver.log',
        # Set to name of database in DATABASES dictionary to enable
        'DATASTORE': 'datastore',
    }
```

What´s wrong with my local geoserver configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your siteurl is set to be http://mygeonode.org, you will also need to add that to allow host form the local_settings.py.

Restart apache2 server and also, if ubuntu, from the terminal run this $ sudo geonode updatelayers

That shall fix it.

Comment: Hi Elai_GEOINT, thanks for your reply. I forgot about that thread but should have closed it. In the end the reason were some "Zombie Layers" in GWC.